# Increasing cost of postgres query

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql-8.4

I have a postgres function like below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.fn_get_status(trans_id character varying) RETURNS character varying 
    AS $$  

DECLARE  

 new_status   varchar;  

BEGIN  

  SELECT status  

  INTO new_status  
  FROM my_schema.my_table
  WHERE id=trans_id;  

  RETURN new_status;  

END;  
$$  
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;  

ALTER FUNCTION my_schema.fn_get_status(trans_id character varying) OWNER TO postgres;
```

It takes more than 30 seconds to execute this function.without this all other functions are got executed within 10 seconds.total around 40 seconds

here `my_table` contains more than 1000 records and some of `trans_id` we are passing here is equals to dash(-) and unfortunately some of the `my_table` ids also having `-` values when I go into it.I think it is the reason for increasing cost of that query.

Is it the actual reason for that and then any idea how can I solve this?

thanks in advanced.

Comment: Is there an actual reason to have that simple thing as a function and what is the actual question?

Comment: Can you post the data structure of my_table? maybe it's because the lack of indexes..

Comment: I know that this one is simple.but cant add new code or new function here as it is inside at my workplace but I can alter this function.this function makes more time with dash checking inside where clause

Comment: @User2012384 I don't have the data structure this moment. but what do you mean by lack of indexes here? status column is indexed here

Comment: Oh sorry misunderstand your question.... but how long would it take if you just run the query: SELECT status  
  FROM my_schema.my_table
  WHERE id='-'; (not calling from the stored procedure)

Comment: @User2012384 then it got executed with integer in seconds.when trans_id become '-' query got stuck

Comment: can I add 'if' condition here with when the 'trans-id' becomes '-' and then add '0'

Comment: do you have many records with id '-'? if you're trying to fetch the first record's status then try adding limit 1 at the end of the query

Comment: yes..I pass another table column values as the 'trans-id' here one by one

Comment: So do you want the new_status to be empty of the trans_id is '-'?

Comment: yes..It should be empty

Comment: @bews99 Take a look at my answer, see if this helps

Answer (score 0):

Trying doing a checking at the beginning:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.fn_get_status(trans_id character varying) RETURNS character varying 
    AS $$  

DECLARE  

 new_status   varchar;  

BEGIN  
  if trans_id = '-' then
   return '';
  end if;    

  SELECT status  

  INTO new_status  
  FROM my_schema.my_table
  WHERE id=trans_id limit 1;  

  RETURN new_status;  

END;  
$$  
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;  

ALTER FUNCTION my_schema.fn_get_status(trans_id character varying) OWNER TO postgres;
```

If possible, try joining the my_schema.my_table outside as the performance will drop a bit if you pass in the trans_id one by one

Comment: ok friend..I will check this on tomorrow and inform you back.thanks